# Is it possible to create a filter for the MediaWiki AbuseFilter extension that disallows user names with special characters?

Tags: mediawiki, mediawiki-extensions

Is it possible to create a filter for the MediaWiki AbuseFilter extension that disallows user names with special characters?

I'm having a recurring vandal problem and basically I want to only allow usernames with characters A through Z and 0 through 9.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, with `action === 'createaccount'`:

```
action === 'createaccount' &
accountname rlike '[^A-Z0-9]'
```

Basically, this checks if a `createaccount` action has an `accountname` that matches the regex `[^A-Z0-9]`, and block it if the result is true. See [the documentation page](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:AbuseFilter/Rules_format) for more information about rules.

Note that this also disallow spaces (underscores are normalized as spaces) and lowercase letters. If this is not what you want, change the regex to `[^A-Za-z0-9 ]`.

Alternatively, you can place the following line into your [MediaWiki:Titleblacklist](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:TitleBlacklist#Usage) page:

```
.*[^a-z0-9 ].*  <newaccountonly>
```

TitleBlacklist is case-insensitive by default, so `A-Z` is not necessary here. However, depending on your needs you might want to modify that by using the `casesensitive` specifier: `<newaccountonly|casesensitive>`.